# Access to query in concern module method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model user.rb and concern query_filter.rb.

```
module QueryFilter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def apply(attr)

  end

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend QueryFilter
end
```

I would like to apply filters for whole model or for query. 
For example:

```
> User.apply(attributes)
=> #query
> User.where(sex: 'male').apply(attributes)
=> #query
```

I have two problems. 
First of all I don't know how can I access to query on which I have called my method in module method? 
<del>Secondly `User.apply(attributes)` won't work, I can use `User.all.apply(attributes)` but that's not the case. Is there any possibility to call method right after class name nor query ?</del>

Answer (score 0):

You have to `include QueryFilter` instead of `extend`

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

But I think for the desired effect you should look into [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) more than concerns.

Comment: it doesn't help with anything, if I use include I can call my method on single object... I want to call it on query or whole class

Comment: ah you are right, I need to include it and then add my method in concern to ClassMethods module, but still I cannot access to relation on which I have called this method

Comment: I fear this is the completely wrong approach for that - since `where` doesnt return a `User` object.